# Topic: Error:Operation not yet implemented,when Exporting pdf from crystal report

Tags: pdf, export

When i am trying to export crystal report to PDF i am getting an error like
Export to PDF failed,operation not yet implemented.What could be the reason
Appreciate if anybody can help me on this,Thanks